# How to safely invite freelancers to a part of your web-project?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, github, tfs

I am looking for a safe method to invite freelancers to help with some tasks on our web-site, and where the freelancer only have write access to some pages.

I know that this is done in example Windows Team Foundation Server. But in this case, the freelancer should be able to "run" the full site, testing that the webpage is ok. And maybe it is me, I cant see those functions on TFS or GitHub. And again without being able to access the code on the other pages.

> Example. I have a website, with 2
>   pages and 1 class.
>
> - Webpage1. Closed to the freelancer. The freelancer may not edit or see the code.
> - Webpage2. The freelancer have read/write access
> - Class. The freelancer may call the public methods of the class, but not edit/see the code.
> - The website. The freelancer may run the full website on the developement server, and browse it

Comment: No way to achieve that, I think the requirements are in conflict. for webpage1 you closed to the freelancer, but you want to the freelancer to run the full website and test the pages ok. As my understanding webpage1 is included in the website, right? If it is , that means the freelancer can not see or edit the webpage1, how do they run the full website? Please correct me if the understand is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, it is correct understood. I have been searching more, and I dont think tools like that exists. We have sensitive data, and cant let anybody in. But in some cases, we need to. Today we use WTF with some restrictions. But then it is us, that needs to debug, when we test the website, since the freelancer cant "run" the site. Sometimes it takes more time, than to code it ourselfes, even though it is highly specialised components or jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, in TFS we can create branches and set the user permissions accordingly to access the branches. Just create freelancer user group and set the permission accordingly (give the permission to access to the deployed website).

eg:

Put Webpage1 in **Branch1** and set all the permission to **Deny**  for freelancer group. See below screenshot for your reference (just an example, you can set the permission based on your requirement)

Put Webpage2 in **Branch2** and give the freelancer group **read/write** (set the permissions based on your requirements) permission.

...

They are all merged to **Main** branch
...

Create Admin User/Group and give the permission to build/deploy website from Main branch.

Once they are all ready, The Admin user can merge all the sub branches to Main branch, and build/deploy the website. Then the freelancer can access to the website for testing.

Please see [Permissions and groups defined for Team Services and TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/permissions) for details.

Git/Github should be also have the similar feature settings.

[image]